# Which live distro comes with python3-pyqt5 pre-installed?

Tags: python

Which distro/version's live USB comes with pyqt5 pre-installed?

Comment: Lots of distros allow to have some sort of `answers` files to automate the installation of additional packages as part of an installation. I personally don't know a single distro which installs this package by default but then I only use CentOS, Fedora and sometimes try Ubuntu.

Comment: Because I need it on a non-persistent live disk

Comment: Create your own LiveCD then. Most if not all the distros have their own tools for that.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using a wide range of distros but haven't found one that has py3-pyt5 installed by default. (Since I need that lib for one of my progs).

I'd go for Xubuntu and create your own "distro" like [this](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/LiveCDCustomization)

The reason for Xubuntu is that it is lightweight and very configurable.